# Getting notification if app is startet from pass

Tags: iphone, ios, passbook

There is a possibility to start the corresponding app from a pass inside `passbook`.

Is it possible to get a notification? Maybe in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, with `launchOptions` including the pass?

Comment: You will need to provide some additional information. Do you want to get a passbook notification or one from your app? Do you want to send a message along with the opening of your app?

Answer (score 0):

There is no information about retrieving data that indicates the app was launched from PassBook. In fact it seems that there is no data sent to the app about passbook. Passbook passes launch apps with corresponding App-Id`s. What you can do is check that if there is the pass you are looking for is in the library. You can read from the documentation here :[PassBook Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH6-SW70) But keep in mind that Passbook Development Guidelines state that your passbook pass needs to be independent of an app.

Answer (score 0):

You can set pass `appLaunchURL` which get passed to associated app's  `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:handleOpenURL:` when the app is launched from the pass (see [Passbook Package Format Referece - Associated App Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW7))

Additionally, since iOS 7.0, you can put extra information into pass `userInfo`, which can be access by associated app via `PKPass`'s `localizedValueForFieldKey:` (see [Passbook Programming Library - Reading a Pass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH6-SW72))